# Accessing inline type in the constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this:

```
export class QueueEntity<T> implements HasInternalQueue<T> {
    
    
    opts: { // <--- inline type here
        foo: boolean
    }
    
    constructor(v: typeof this.opts) { // this doesn't quite work
        this.opts = v
    }

}
```

is there a way to reference the inline type or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no way to define a type inside the class directly (An [open](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038) issue in the TS repo).  I think you can use the class name to reference `this`:

```
export class QueueEntity<T> {
   
    
    opts: { // <--- inline type here
        foo: boolean
    }
    
    constructor(v: QueueEntity<T>['opts']) { //  <-- should work now
        this.opts = v
    }

}

const obj = new QueueEntity({ foo : false });
const obj2 = new QueueEntity({ foo2 : false });
const obj3 = new QueueEntity();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EUCuw8CiAdjAJYwCeAPACoB8cA3gFBxtwCOeeAXHAIJQoKavTgBeOAG0AugG5W7RWwhgYaPozgB6bXCoBaI3FJEkp4HEphLAC2BRgy9mwBmECHwBGHpMBREzgC+zM6kaAQAtmoUABQAlN6+-kRMzi6OMDhQqTC24QB0XPjABX5EAOZ5+nAAjAouIS7OCBBEaDBQOAgw0LEAbny4JcRklLR0UgDkqupTMvFMOnp54XAAJhDAaERT8FzklgDu0ADW6eyraAWzmJL9waEhzK3t8BBeAFYScETAR9huMBRuQ4lp3BA4HxXCgkGhLEF4gpXh04B9PgAmH5-AHDQgkUGxcEeLHQ2HwuCI5FtVHogDM2P+gJGBMoCQUQA)